# If else condition in the controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. How can I place an if condition in the controller, in pseudocode, I'd like to achieve the following:

```
if @friend.status is pending
  link_to redirect to path 
else
  link_to redirect to another path
end
```

This is my current code:

```
<% @value.each do |s| %>
<h2>Friend Request</h2>
<p><%= link_to s.message %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: in ERB you can use the same constructs and syntax as in ruby, that's why it's called ERB: Embedded RuBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is pending a method that you can call on each @value item? If so:

```
<% @value.each do |s| %>
  <% if s.pending %>
    <% do some stuff in ruby %>
    <div>Bit of HTML if you want</div>
  <% else %>
    <% do some stuff in ruby %>
    <div>Bit of HTML if you want</div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Side note - if @value is a collection then it's probably best to call it @values and then do

```
@values.each do |value|
```

Comment: By practice is it ok to put conditions in the html? or should I place it somewhere else like in the controller or helper ?

Comment: I may have people disagree with me but I've always put conditionals in the html. The only other option would be to have your controller or a helper method return html after it has done the conditional, and then just call that method in the view, but that's probably more hassle than its worth imho